# How to create spacing above a HTML element, but only after the first one?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I am creating a list of some HTML elements using a for loop with Twig that display within a Bootstrap popover. I want to have a space between each element, but not before the first or after the last.

What I want:

```
@Header Text
  info text
  text text text text text text
    <spacing here>
    <spacing here>
@ Header Text
  info text
  text text text text text text
```

The twig code starting at the for loop creating each info element

```
{% block content %}
{% for namesArrayIndex in 0..(section.getInstructorNamesArrayCount()-1)  %}
<div>

<span class="fa fa-user instructor-contact-info-header"></span>
    <div class="contact-info-container">
        <p class="instructor-contact-info-header"> . 
            {{section.getInstructorNamesArray()[namesArrayIndex]}}</p>
    {% set email = section.getInstructorEmails()[namesArrayIndex] %}
        <p class = "instructor-contact-info-data"> 
            <a  href="mailto: {{ email }}"> {{ email }} </a> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a css problem to me.

```
.instructor:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: using this method would I need to create the first-child and last-child classeS?

Comment: @d1596, they are psuedo-class selectors. So you won't have to use them in your html, just in your CSS

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add html tags like

```
</br>
```

to your popovers just add the attribute

```
data-html="true"
```

to the a tag of the popover